# Vim does not show changes when switching to other branch or running black from terminal within

Tags: python, vim

If I run black to fix formatting from a terminal buffer that is opened within vim, I don't see the changes. I need to reload vim in order to see that. Same thing happens if I switch between git branches in the terminal buffer from within vim. How can I solve that? I have `set autoread` in my `.vimrc` but I don't think it's doing something...

Answer (score 1):

Vim doesn't watch your files so enabling `autoread` alone won't automagically reload your buffers. You still have to do something manually:

- do `:edit` on the current buffer,
- do `<C-^><C-^>` to switch to the alternate file and back,
- do `:checktime %` to check if the current file has been changed,
- do `:checktime` to do that check for every file,
- and possibly other ways.

As for running your formatter from `:terminal`, why not telling Vim to use it directly for formatting with `:help gq` (`gggqG`, `gqip`, etc.):

```
" in after/ftplugin/python.vim
set formatprg=black\ --stdin-filename\ %\ --fast\ --quiet\ -
```